# Vietnamese branch of international company with too few sick leave days

Tags: labor-law, vietnam

Suppose that a person A  recently got a job in Vietnam from an international company based in Europe. FIt ism my understanding that the minimal sick leave days required in Vietnam is 30 days, but this company has it in the single digits.

Is this company violating Vietnamese labor laws? If yes, what can A do about it?

Comment: If the minimal sick days is 30 and they are giving 9 or less that sounds like they are violating the law.

Comment: This is going to depend on the exact provisions of Vietnamese law.  I don't know if that law is available in an official English-language version. I don't know if any poster here reads Vietnamese  well enough to make an informed answer if there is no English-language version. Given the history, perhaps a French-language version is available.

Comment: Just wondering: Is A Vietnamese / has always lived in Vietnam / get a typical Vietnamese salary. Or are they for example French, moved to Vietnam by their company, paid a typical French salary?

Answer (score 1):

**Such a person is not necessarily covered by Vietnamese employment law.**

It is common for employees from one country to work in another - that does not automatically make them subject to the second country’s employment law. Temporary overseas assignments (which can be days, weeks, months, or even years) generally do not change the jurisdiction of the employment contract providing the intention is that the employee will return at the employer’s cost at the end.

The particulars depend on the details of each nation’s laws and any treaties between them as well as the terms of the employment contract and the actual situation.